# Manipulate FontAwesome with Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, font-awesome-5

I'm working on a little project to learn more about Javascript so I can work on svg animations in the future.

Now I'm working on a button that will change his input when you click on it.

```js
circle = document.getElementById('circle');
$remove = document.getElementById('remove');
remove.style.display = "block";
$undo   = document.getElementById('undo');
undo.style.display = "none";

circle.onclick = function() {
  remove.style.display = "none";
  undo.style.display   = "block";
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background-color: #10ac84;
  border-radius: 50%;
} 
.circle svg  { font-size: 1.5em; }
```

```html
<div class="circle" id="circle">
  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" id="remove"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-undo" id="undo"></i>
</div>
```

It's a little hard to put it in a snippet because I can't load the font awesome cdn.

**-| What I'm trying to do |-**

When you enter the page the circle will have an icon on a trashcan.
When the user clicks the circle the trashcan will disappear and the undo icon will show up. 
This is for removing an item in my application and undo it when you want it back.

**-| Question |-**

Can I remove and add style to FontAwesome icons? Because it will transform into SVG's

*I hope that I have explained it well and that someone can help me out.*

Project: http://www.projectnova.nl/changeClick/

Comment: Are you using the SVG-with-JS method or the WebFonts-with-CSS method?

Comment: Yes, i do. [fa-svg-with-js.css] and [fontawesome-all.min.js]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to target the right element whenever you use the [SVG with JavaScript](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) method.  There won't be an `<i>` for you to select after the replacement.

Font Awesome uses [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to know when it needs to change the SVG after you change the class.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const icon = evt.currentTarget.querySelector("svg");
  if (icon.classList.contains("fa-user")) {
    icon.classList.remove("fa-user");
    icon.classList.add("fa-github-square");
  } else {
    icon.classList.remove("fa-github-square");
    icon.classList.add("fa-user");
  }
});
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-Voup2lBiiyZYkRto2XWqbzxHXwzcm4A5RfdfG6466bu5LqjwwrjXCMBQBLMWh7qR" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button><i class="fas fa-user"></i></button>
```

Comment: I see it works for you. But in my current setup it won't work.. I'll start a new project soon and I will see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your input. Helps a lot.

Comment: In case anyone is concerned, IE10 does NOT support `const`.

Comment: Not even with 'use strict'?

Answer (score 1):

**Be advised, this method only works when using Font Awesome with CSS. To use the JavaScript with SVG method, look at the other answer.**

This would be easier to accomplish if you used a single `i` tag and dynamically changed the icon `class`.

For example:

```
<div class="circle">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" id="remove"></i>
</div>
```

Then you just flip between the `fa-undo` and `fa-trash-alt` classes.

```
// select the element
var removalIcon = document.querySelector("#remove");

// add event listener
removalIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.className = "fas fa-undo";
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It won't change the class name.
Maybe because Font Awesome changes I tags into SVG?

When i console.log the I tag it changed the class names. But on the page nothing changed.

Comment: This should work with the JS method as well.  Font Awesome uses mutation observers to watch the class list of the element to know when it needs to regenerate the SVG.  The `id` will be put onto the new `<svg>` element (along with any other attributes).  The issue is that you are caching the selected element.  Attach the listener to the `.circle` and query select for the `#remove` on each click.