# How do I change a icon upon clicking it in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I have this

```
<div class="container">
    <button id="menu-sound" class="btn video-icon" onclick="SoundOnAndOff()">
        <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

and in js

```
$('#menu-sound').click(function(){
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-volume-up').toggleClass('fa-volume-off');
});
```

Why don't work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manipulate FontAwesome with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241622/manipulate-fontawesome-with-javascript)

Comment: What version of font-awesome are you using?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: What version of font awesome?  they moved to svg elements with 5 and the `<i>` tag is commented out in the frontend code now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, mistake in library. This work fine.

```js
$('#menu-sound').click(function(){
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-volume-up').toggleClass('fa-volume-off');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <button id="menu-sound" class="btn video-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The example that you've provided works perfectly fine. There will be another problem. Maybe your libraries are not loading correctly. So find out more about debugging your code and you'll find the problem pretty soon.

```js
$('#menu-sound').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-volume-up').toggleClass('fa-volume-off');
});

function SoundOnAndOff() {
  console.log('toggling sound');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <button id="menu-sound" class="btn video-icon" onclick="SoundOnAndOff()">
        <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

**Further reading:**

[Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542251/liam) answered already [How can I debug my JavaScript code? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code#19623573)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem in another way. You can see my [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/wt7R0HyM4aJLt2zY4q7V?p=preview) here.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-sound').click(function() {
    console.log($('#icon-menu-sound').hasClass('fa-volume-up'));
    if ($('#icon-menu-sound').hasClass('fa-volume-up')) {
      $('#icon-menu-sound').removeClass('fa-volume-up');
      $('#icon-menu-sound').addClass('fa-volume-off');
    } else if ($('#icon-menu-sound').hasClass('fa-volume-off')) {
      $('#icon-menu-sound').removeClass('fa-volume-off');
      $('#icon-menu-sound').addClass('fa-volume-up');
    }
  });
});
```

I've changed the HTML a bit

```
<div class="container">
<button id="menu-sound" class="btn video-icon">
<i id='icon-menu-sound' class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</button>
```