# Why class gets removed from classList, but not from the target event itself?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, font-awesome-5

I have a list of paragraphs generated dynamically, each one with an svg for a sync icon (fontawesome) as a child element. When the user clicks on the icon, a class of `fa-spin` is added causing the icon to spin. After some asynchronous code, simulated below by `setTimeout()`, I want to remove the newly-added `fa-spin` class to have it added again the next time the icon is clicked. The problem is that `event.target.classList.remove('fa-spin');` is not working. By running some `console.log()` calls I can see that the `classList` indeed gets the class removed and even the element shows up as no longer having it, however, if I check it the "*Elements*" tab of the dev tools and the UI itself, the svg still has the class and therefore the icon keeps on spinning.

Please note that `toggle()` is not the behavior I'm looking for because upon a click the class should always be added again.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="version-control-tms">
    <div id="version-control-repos">
      <h2>Version control repos</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tms-projects">
      <h2>TMS projects</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Paragraph.js**

```
export default class Paragraph {

  constructor(items, placement) {

    this.items = items;
    this.placement = placement;

}

  create() {

    this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
        const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
        let placeInUI = document.querySelector(this.placement);
        paragraph.setAttribute('class', 'resource');
        paragraph.textContent = item.name;
        placeInUI.appendChild(paragraph);
        this.implementUpdateIcon(index);
    });
  }

implementUpdateIcon (item) {

  const resource = document.getElementsByClassName('resource')[item];
  const child = document.createElement('spam');
  child.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-sync-alt');
  resource.append(child);
}
```

}

**main.js**

```
  document.getElementById('version-control-tms').addEventListener('click', event => {

      if (event.target.classList.contains('fa-sync-alt')) {
    
        event.target.classList.add('fa-spin');

        // Run some asynchronous code...
        setTimeout(() => {
          event.target.classList.remove('fa-spin');
        }, 3000);

      }

    }, false);
```

**Console output after adding the class**

```
DOMTokenList(4) ["svg-inline--fa", "fa-sync-alt", "fa-w-16", "fa-spin", 
value: "svg-inline--fa fa-sync-alt fa-w-16 fa-spin"]
```

**Console output after removing the class**

```
DOMTokenList(3) ["svg-inline--fa", "fa-sync-alt", "fa-w-16", value: "svg-inline--fa fa-sync-alt fa-w-16"]
```

**Element in the DOM**

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-sync-alt fa-w-16 fa-spin" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="sync-alt" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""></svg>
```

Comment: there is too much brackets closing btw.

Comment: Sorry, the last one was related to code that comes before the one I pasted here. I've now removed it.

Comment: I have tested the above code in the snippet and it works as intended. Please ensure that your snippet actually contains the problem you are describing. Within this context, I don't think it _could_ go wrong. I can foresee that potentially using a framework that renders your HTML separetely (like react or angular) might add a new element at some point, making the `event.target` referencing the wrong element, but otherwise this should work.

Comment: I'm actually using vanilla JS only here. However, it may be important to mention that this code is run only after a Promise has resolved because I have to wait for data to return from API calls so that the paragraphs are generated.

Comment: Again, that shouldn't make a difference - because of the scope of your event listener the target shouldn't change, if you are directly pulling it from the event object passed in then running any asynchronous operation there shouldn't change the target at all. But the code you have posted in the question does not illustrate the problem at all, so maybe have a look at that first.

Answer (score 0):

I tested you Code and it seems to work. You can test the snippet:

```js
class Paragraph {

  constructor(items, placement) {

    this.items = items;
    this.placement = placement;

}

  create() {

    this.items.forEach((item) => {
        const paragraphElem = document.createElement('p');
        let placeInUI = document.querySelector(this.placement);
        paragraphElem.classList.add('resource');
        paragraphElem.textContent = item.name;
        placeInUI.appendChild(paragraphElem);
        this.implementUpdateIcon(paragraphElem);
    });
  }

  implementUpdateIcon(paragraphElem) {
      let spanElem = document.createElement('span');
      spanElem.innerHTML = "click me!";
      spanElem.classList.add('fas', 'fa-sync-alt');
      paragraphElem.append(spanElem);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
    let x = new Paragraph([{name: 'hello world!'}, {name: 'hello world!'}, {name: 'hello world!'}, {name: 'hello world!'}, {name: 'hello world!'}, {name: 'hello world!'}], '#tms-projects');
    x.create();
    
    document.getElementById('version-control-tms').addEventListener('click', event => {

      if (event.target.classList.contains('fa-sync-alt')) {
    
        event.target.classList.add('fa-spin');

        // Run some asynchronous code...
        setTimeout(() => {
          event.target.classList.remove('fa-spin');
        }, 3000);

      }

    }, false);

}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.fa-spin {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
 <div id="version-control-tms">
    <div id="version-control-repos">
      <h2>Version control repos</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tms-projects">
      <h2>TMS projects</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Things I notice (already changed in the snippet):

- `document.createElement('spam')` should be `document.createElement('span')`.
- `child.classList.add('fas', 'fa-sync-alt')` can be used instead of  `child.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-sync-alt')` same with `paragraph.setAttribute('class', 'resource')`. But keep in mind that IE and Opera Mini can't handle multiple classes like so. Maybe two times `classList.add` is a better solution.
- you can pass the paragraph element directly to the `implementUpdateIcon' function and don't need an index for it:

  ```
  implementUpdateIcon (paragraphElem) {
     let spanElem = document.createElement('span');
     spanElem.classList.add('fas', 'fa-sync-alt');
     paragraphElem.append(child);
  }
  ```

Comment: Hello! Just telling you that this is not an answer, and should be a comment. I can see you don't have the reputation for a comment yet, but this 'answer' isn't going to help...

Comment: Actually, that's pretty much my code with the additional JSON.stringify(). As I had said, the classist really shows that the class was removed in the console, but the DOM element itself remains with the class.

By the way, the id belongs to an ancestor element that I'm targeting so I can use event delegation bubbling in the icon, so it's not in the paragraph iself.

Comment: @somethinghere I have edited it a bit. I hope it is a little better now. But right. It is not a solution. 
Your example code works. If it not works for you, try a other Browser. The JSON.stringify trick is only to ensure that things are really there and not later on.

Comment: @JGTrindade The snippet in this 'answer' (sorry!) does illustrate that the code you posted in your question is functioning _as expected_, and has no issues in it. If you can't replicate the problem with your code, then something else is doing it, and we need that code included as well to be able to help further.

Comment: @somethinghere, I added the class that is generated the paragraph, but it's actually being used as a module by another class and that, in turn, is used main.js. I just don't don't know if can be of any help, since that code is pretty much "isolated". The event listener is working as expected to add the class and the classList in the console shows that it's also working to be removed, it's just not happening in the element itself.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, @Josh. For now, let me answer the one that matters the most for my question: I'm listening for click events on version-control-tms because I had to use event delegation with bubbling to be able to catch a click on my icons, otherwise the paragraph, which its parent, was catching them all. That's all I have an if statement to where the code only runs if the target is the icon and not the paragraph or anything else inside version-control-tms. The class, though, is being added as expected to the svg icon.

Comment: The async code doesn't exist yet, I just added the comment because there'll be plenty of async code on that spot and at the very end the class should be removed so that the sync icon stops spinning. Then, the next time it's clicked again, the class will be added, the async code will run again and the class will be removed once the async data is fetched. I just wanted to test the class removal before moving forward since the async code shouldn't influence it in any ways.

Comment: @JGTrindade I have updated the answer. I think the problem could be caused by the way you load the Javascript module or by DOM manipulations from other sources.

Comment: Again, the issue isn't actually in the code provided. Unless something calls create() (and cleares the dom before calling it) could cause this, since the event listener is entirely in it's own scope, so `event.target` should not change, so if you could add it, removing it should also work. I still cannot see anything in your code that would prevent it from working.

Comment: create() is called inside another module that I didn't add here because I'll end up putting lots of code here when, in fact, what @somethinghere said is true, the event listener is in its own scope and should work regardless since create() doesn't clear the DOM, it only creates the paragraphs and is working. Now... Could it be an issue with the remove() method being inside the setTimeout() callback? I'm asking it because when I remove setTimeout() and simply apply remove() right after add(), it works as expected.

Comment: Hi @JGTrindade No it has nothing to do with the setTimeout() Method (Did you try my Snippet? It works without problems.).
I think the easiest thing you can do is to add a `debugger;` before the remove() and examine what is not working. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: Hi @Josh. That's right, there's nothing to do with setTimeout, but it has something to do with the way fontawesome works with svgs. I'm checking the docs again because everything worked when I tested the same code with another element on my page. fontawesome comments out the span created as an inline element and replaces it with svgs. It should work anyway, since it works for adding classes, but there's some quirk that I'm now investigating. I'll write here as soon as I understand it all.

Comment: Ok, I made it work by referencing fontawesome through css instead of js. When this is done fontawesome doesn't replace the span created by an svg and it works as such. There should be a reason for this svg replacement. I think it's related to what is discussed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241892/4229541. But I need to further investigate and read about the MutationObserver interface (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to understand it.

Comment: ahhh nice to hear that you have found it